# How to create indexes on MQT(materialized query table) in Db2?

Tags: db2, query-optimization, materialized-views

How to create indexes on MQT(materialized query table) in Db2? I haven't found this information in documentation? Is index  creation syntax the same as for common tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create your MQT you have to refresh the table before you can create indexes.  However, at this point it's exactly the same as creating indexes on a normal table.

There are some limitations on what type of indexes you can create on an MQT. For example, it cannot be a unique index.

Comment: Just to add to this question - in an MQT you need to include the primary key columns from all the source tables. Do you need to add indexes on those columns to speed up the data syncing from the source tables?

Comment: @sapatos It depends on how you refresh the table – if you are doing a full refresh, then having a unique index isn't necessary.  But, if you are doing incremental refreshes (or have refresh immediate) then having as close to a unique index as possible is very important.

Comment: yeah I came to the same conclusion via experimentation. Without the indexes on each primary key the table refresh performance was horrible. It surprised me as with refresh LIVE I'd expect DB2 to set up the required indexes as its the underlying operating system that's maintaining the table